# How to fix the size of a table and keep the structure remains?

Tags: tables, resize, tag

The purpose is to create a table as a template so I can build my price tags.

The table I've built using Tex is:

[image: The result of current Tex]

And the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % Use pdflscape package for landscape page
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % For adjustbox package

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}  % Start landscape mode
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=7cm,height=3.8cm,keepaspectratio}  % Add keepaspectratio
\begin{tabular}{|lllll|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l}{Brand} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Barcode} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l}{Name} & \multirow{4}{*}{Price1} & \multirow{4}{*}{Price2} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l}{Size} & & \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l}{CSPC} & & \\
Flag & SweetPicture & Sweetness & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}  % End landscape mode

\end{document}
```

But I found out that as I change the text in the cells, the table would be resized.
The Brand and Name sometimes get longer, so I need to use something to make their font sizes dynamically adaptive. For example, for the longer name, its font gets smaller to be **just enough to fill that cell**.

Here is an example of the layout I want. I use HTML in this example but the "Name" field here cannot adjust by itself, so it gets overflowed.

[image]

Comment: If You correct code for `\multirow` cells (should be `\multirow{4}{*}{...}`, observe *) , than your MWE gives what you after. What is than problem?

Comment: With `\begin{tabular}{p{3cm]}` or `\begin{tabular}{p{.3\linewidth}}` you will have a table with a column of 3cm  or 30% of the line width, no matter of the  content.  Of course, use adjustbox with table with p columns (and without p columns) is just a bad idea.